# How to use Dynamic query in linq to entites?

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I am using linq to entites and I want to use the dynamic query in it?
is it possible?

```
                    var datas = (from u in _context.Users
                             where u.AlfId == 25
                             select new
                             {
                                 u.Id,
                                 UpdatedByUserName = "select * from dbo.abc(u.Id)"
                             }
                            ).OrderByDescending(m => m.Id).ToList();
```

Comment: This query can be written by LINQ, do you really need dynamic?

Comment: I want to use a mix of linq to entities and also dynamic in it like above I have shown

Comment: Ok, dynamic LINQ is not an option? Or you have fully dynamic database structure?